# Qual a melhor tradução para "Boolean", do Inglês? Booleano, ou Booliano?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, diferenças-regionais

Eu já vi os dois termos sendo usados. Qual a melhor tradução, e onde estes dois termos são mais utilizados? Seria o caso de booleano ser mais utilizado nos países do acordo ortográfico, e Booliano na Europa?

Comment: Nota: Não, na europa "nunca" se grafa *booliano*; em 20 anos de programação acho que é a primeira vez que leio isso escrito com i. Acho que isto se deve à influência da palavra inglesa "boolean".

Comment: @ANeves a grafia com i é preferida pelo acordo ortográfico, que sofreu bastante resistencia na Europa.

Answer (score 3):

Os termos *booleano* e *booliano* constam no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/), [VOC](https://voc.cplp.org/index.php?sel=start&action=simplesearch&base=form&query=bool), [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v6-1/html/index.php#1), mas apenas *bool**i**ano* constam no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/) e [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/booliano/).

Qual é melhor? Como programador amador brasileiro, esta é a primeira vez que vejo *bool**i**ano*. Eu sempre vi e ouvi *bool**e**ano*. Procurando na internet, vi poquíssimos usos de *bool**i**ano*. No final, os dois são certos, mas aparentemente *bool**e**ano* domina o uso.

Porém, os dicionários ou listam apenas *bool**i**ano* ou chamam *bool**e**ano* de sinônimo. Isto talvez se dê pelo que diz o Houaiss:

> no âmbito da língua de cultura, vem impondo-se uma regra segundo a qual só se escreverá -*eano* quando a sílaba tônica do derivante for um -*e*- tônico ou ditongo tônico com base -*e*- ou, por fim, em que, mesmo átono, o -*e*- for seguido de vogal átona: arqueano (Arqueu), cuneano (Cuneo/Cúneo), daomeano (Daomé), egeano (Egeu), galileano (Galileu), lineano (Lineu); os demais, mesmo que as palavras de que tenham derivado se grafem com e, serão sempre em -iano: acriano (Acre), camiliano, ciceroniano, eciano, freudiano, leniniano, zwingliano etc.

A resposta não é satisfatória. Porém, ao que parece, os dois estão certos, mas *bool**i**ano* é mais culto, mesmo que muito menos comum.

Como nota, quando estiver se referindo a valor booleano que seja ou verdadeiro ou falso, poderá usar *lógico*, como faz o [Portugol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugol).

Comment: Suponho que a pronúncia brasileira típica do nome "Boole" seja /búle/, ao invés do original /buːl/ e que isto, juntamente com a grafia inglesa "_Boolean_", contribua para a preferência pela versão com "e".

Comment: @stafusa Tua suposição está correta. O E ao final do nome "Boole" sai com sonoridade, diferentemente do E praticamente mudo da língua Inglesa.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o acordo ortográfico de 1990,

> De acordo com o ponto 3 da base IX do Acordo Ortográfico de 1945, a
> que poderá aceder seguindo a hiperligação, o adjectivo referente ao
> arquipélago dos Açores escreve-se com i, pois grafam-se com i, antes
> da sílaba tónica, os adjectivos e substantivos derivados com os
> sufixos -ense e -ano, aos quais se apõe um i para formar as
> terminações -iense e -iano. Nesta regra incluem-se palavras como
> açoriano, acriano, cabo-verdiano, camoniano ou torriense.
>
> O Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 [ver Base V, 2.º, alínea c)] não alterou
> nada relativamente a este ponto para o português europeu. Esta
> indicação de escrever com i e não com e os derivados em que entram os
> sufixos -iano e -iense não estava prevista no Formulário Ortográfico
> de 1943, que regulava a ortografia brasileira, pelo que o português do
> Brasil, depois da aplicação do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, deverá
> sofrer esta pequena alteração. [[1]](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1525)

O correto seria grafar o termo com -iano ao invés de -eano.